# teb local planner - min obstacle height to put in local cost map

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, teb-local-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a parameter that lets me specify the min height of the obstacle to put in the teb local planner,like there is with Trajectory planner ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264256/teb-local-planner---min-obstacle-height-to-put-in-local-cost-map/) by [Aswath](https://answers.ros.org/users/26370/aswath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can configure that parameter in your local costmap, which is then used by the teb local planner

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0